# Methods with bank account

Tags: java

I have been writing a program for banking, but I am having issues with changing my current balance after a withdraw. It works the first time, but goes back to original amount the second time. Like if I have $300, then withdraw $50, it will show $250. However, after it executes a second time and I withdraw $20, it will show my balance is $280 instead of $230.
My program needs to have two methods plus a `main` method, and my current account balance is $300. Also it needs a main menu.

My teacher said we cannot use arrays because we haven't discussed it yet.
This is my first time using more than just a `main` method so my choice of methods might be wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankingATM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double withdraw = withdrawAmount();
        double myBalance = withdrawAmount();
        balanceAmount(withdraw, myBalance);
    }

    public static double withdrawAmount() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option;
        double myBalance;
        double withdraw = 0;
        myBalance = 300 - withdraw;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please select an option:");
            System.out.println("Press 1 the withdraw from you account.");
            System.out.println("Press 2 to check your balance");
            System.out.println("Press 3 to Exit");
            {
                option = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (option == 1) {
                    System.out.println("User selected to withdraw");
                    System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
                    withdraw = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    myBalance = 300;
                    double newBalance = myBalance - withdraw;
                    {
                        if (withdraw > 500) {
                            System.out.println("Sorry but the ATM has a limit of $500.00");
                        } else if (withdraw > myBalance && withdraw > 500) {
                            System.out.println("Sorry your account only has $300.00");
                        } else if (withdraw > myBalance) {
                            System.out.println("Sorry your account only has $300.00");
                        } else if (withdraw <= myBalance) {
                            System.out.println("The machine is realeasing $" + withdraw);
                            System.out.println("Your current balance is $" + (myBalance - withdraw));
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (option == 2) {
                    System.out.println("User selected to check balance");
                    balanceAmount(withdraw, myBalance);
                }
                if (option == 3) {
                    System.out.println("User chose to exit");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        } while (option != 1 || option != 2 || option != 3);
        return myBalance;
    }

    public static void balanceAmount(double withdraw, double myBalance) {
        System.out.println("Your balance is" + myBalance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, anytime you withdraw money, you initialize the balance back to 300 :

```
    if(option == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("User selected to withdraw");
        System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
        withdraw = keyboard.nextDouble();
        myBalance = 300; // you should remove that line.
```

In addition, if you intend to call `withdrawAmount()` multiple times, you shouldn't declare the `myBalance` variable as a local variable inside that method, since each call to the method will reset the balance.

Comment: You should also should also remove the second initialization of `myBalance` before calculating the `newBalance`

Comment: Thank you, but when i remove it, parts of my program tells me that i have to declare myBalance. Should i put it in the main method? If so, how would i call on it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
 myBalance = 300; // you should remove that line.
```

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low-quality. You should add some precisions on you answer and on why it should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In do.. while loop , make following changes :
//myBalance = 300; //remove this line
double myBalance = myBalance - withdraw; // assign new value too myBalance